# How to make a dynamic options menu?

Tags: android

The problem is that the following method gets called one time when the Menu button is pressed:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

How can I recreate the menu at a later time in order to change some options, disable some options, etc?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Override this
onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);

        if (item != null) {
         item.setVisible (shouldIShowThisItem)
        }
}
```

Comment: That worked great.  To anyone else doing this, before you can change the menu items in onPrepareOptionsMenu you need to do a menu.clear() to clear out the current stuff.

Comment: You don't need to clear the menu if you're only changing existing items. If you're regenerating or reinflating an entirely new menu you may want to.

Comment: I was unable to change the menu items without clearing and recreating it.  I tried getting an individual item with menu.getPositon() but when I changed the Title the changes were not reflected in the menu.

Comment: If you're using 3.0 or higher, call "invalidateOptionsMenu()" to have a menu be prepared again.

Comment: you should return true from this method. If you return false, the menu is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

if you want to push the menu changes use this.