# How to implement a secret menu

Tags: android, android-menu

For the sake of testing a feature that I don't want to release **yet** to the general public, I would like to implement a "secret" menu or menu item.

By "secret" I don't mean truly secret but more of a hidden or invisible menu, accessible to the developer (me) only, by entering a code or some other mechanism.

It's not the end of the world if an end-user finds about it and attempts to use it ("They made it idiot proof, but I found a workaround."). I just don't want to fail the unsuspecting innocent lay end-user, by providing a feature that isn't fully tested yet.

Any suggestions on how to go about this? (Android 2.2 and up only)

Comment: Why would you need to release it and keep it hidden? Also an update with nothing for the user is a waste of time for the user.

Comment: @Matsemann Because I want to test the same exact binary that the end-user has, not a re-build. Nowhere did I imply "an update with nothing for the user"... Suggestions?

Comment: I'm just curious :) Also, when dealing with a problem, it's good to know WHATs and WHYs. Maybe we cannot answer your exact question, but can give another solution etc.  Why would it matter not using the exact same build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach I've used a couple of times is to pop up a PIN entry form when the user triple-taps a particular part of the screen.  You enter the PIN, you get through to the developer screen.

Comment: Great idea. Does this imply a dynamically instantiated menu instead of a resource-based one?

Comment: No.  The only thing that needs to be special is how you trigger it. Though obviously, it can't be implemented as a menu that already is special and has associated means of triggering, like the options menu, unless you make it a dynamic part thereof.

Comment: This tip, together with http://stackoverflow.com/a/3680926 got me there. The other answers are great too, but I just needed some tip regarding how to trigger the password entry mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

- compare e.g. the Android Id of the device and if it matches your dev phone unlock the menu
- let your app check if another app (some empty dummy) is installed and unlock the menu based on that info.
- you can add an Activity to your code / manifest that is not triggered by any code. You can still start it via `adb shell am start -n com.your.package/.SecretThing` (that activity could simply set a shared preference that unlocks the menu)
- you could trigger a menu if you listen to some secret broadcast you send with `adb shell am broadcast -a your.secret.broacast.ACTION_SECRET`
- if you have a device that has a keyboard implement a key listener that only triggers the menu if you enter some secret word (still forward key events to the system)
- if your app has access to location then hide the menu if your are e.g. not at home.
- add some always visible menu item that triggers a password protected screen (not a good idea but it works)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to have the menu on your development phones only or do you want to get to the menu on any phone?

Here's 3 options I can think of.

1) You could have a file with some arbitrary string key code in it, and the existence of the file and key turns the feature on.

2) You could log screen presses, on your buttons and a combination of this launches the pass code screen.

3) If you have an options menu, with a more section you could burry the pass screen there. Or if you have an about screen, long pressing a logo could launch the pass screen.

Comment: Answering your qusetion: any phone. I'll check your the options you listed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I need a secrete menu too, Well I'm going to implement it on `login screen` , enter `device time` in EditText field and `press cancel`.